# Cron output emails created with delay

Tags: postfix, cron, sendmail

One of our users has a daily cron job which runs for 24 hours. The output is emailed to the user in the usual way. Because the output is piped into sendmail (postfix) over 24 hours, it appears in the queue with a pre-qmgr delay of ~86400 seconds. Our monitoring system then flags an alert as it thinks there's a delivery issue.

Is there any way of preventing this behaviour? Is there any way of getting sendmail to "start the clock" once the inbound pipe from cron has finished?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand that correctly, the better solution would probably be to send the output of the job to a text file and then cat the text file to mail, or send it as an attachment. Holding a postfix thread open probably isn't a problem but it's not elegant.

Comment: Yep, that would be better but re-educating users to write scripts properly instead of relying on the cron-output-gets-emailed-to-you functionality is a pain. It may be the only way to 'fix' the issue, though.

Comment: We used to call it a LART...